# Image in label not appearing in secondary window (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to display an image inside of a label in a second Tkinter window.
In my main window (window), the images are displayed perfectly, but when I write the same code to appear inside of the second window (root), the code executes, but you cannot see the image, only blank space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my relevant code:

```
# Create a variable assigned to the location of the main image, and then change its proportions (the higher the number/s, the smaller)
finance_news_image1 = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Projects\\project\\x\\y\\z\\finance news.gif')
finance_news_image2 = finance_news_image1.subsample(1, 1)

# Create a variable for the main image of the menu, and define its placement within the grid
main_photo = Label(root, image = finance_news_image2)
root.main_photo = main_photo
main_photo.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrongly kept the reference to the image. This means you need to change this line:

```
root.main_photo = main_photo
```

To:

```
main_photo.image = finance_news_image2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now, and your time is greatly appreciated.